# SharePoint 2013 Powershell: Exception calling "AddPublishingPage" with "2" argument(s): "Access is denied"

Tags: sharepoint-server, powershell, publishing-site, access, access-denied

So, I'm trying to create pages via powershell, script below:

```
 # Get the SiteURL
 $SiteUrl = "https://MySiteCollectionURL"

 # Get the WebURL
 $WebUrl = "https://MyWebURL"

 # Get the PageLayout
 $PageLayoutRelUrl = "/_catalogs/masterpage/CustomPageLayout.aspx"

 # Get the Page URL
 $PageName = "Test.aspx"

 # Get the Title of the Page which is going to get created
 $PageTitle = "Test"

 # Initialize the Site Object
 $Site = Get-SPSite($SiteUrl)

 # Get the Publishing Site based on the SPSite
 $PubSite = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.PublishingSite($Site)

 # Get the SPWeb Object
 $Web = Get-SPWeb $WebUrl

 # Initialize the PublishingWeb based on the SPWeb
 $PubWeb = [Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.PublishingWeb]::GetPublishingWeb($Web)

 # Get the PageLayouts Installed on the Publishing Site
 $Layouts = $PubSite.GetPageLayouts($False)

 # Get our PageLayout
 $PageLayout = $Layouts[$PageLayoutRelUrl]

 # Create a new publishing page.
 $Page = $PubWeb.AddPublishingPage($PageName, $PageLayout)

 # Assign the Title for the Page
 $Page.Title = $PageTitle

 # Update the Page
 $Page.Update();

 # Check in the Page with Comments
 $Page.CheckIn("Test Comment")

 # Publish the Page With Comments
 $Page.ListItem.File.Publish("Test Publish Comment")
```

Every time it gets to the `AddPublishingPage` command, it crashes out with the error:

```
Exception calling "AddPublishingPage" with "2" argument(s): "Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))"
```

I have the 'shell window running as administrator, I'm a farm admin, and my account can create pages though the browser.

What gives?

Comment: Do you have access to the content Database ?

Comment: Yeah, I'm basically a top-level admin on every area of the SharePoint farm. I'm wondering if I've set the Publishing site up wrong or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check below two things:

1. You need to use "SharePoint 2013 Management Shell", not using "Windows PowerShell".
2. Make sure you have a CustomPageLayout.aspx file in "Master Page Gallery" library. If not, using "BlankPageLayout.aspx".

Also you need to make sure you can access "Master Page Gallery" library

Comment: imp. - thanks for the tip - realised that the relative URL for the masterpages gallery was for the site, while my custom page was in the root site! stoopid... All fixed. ;)